# Formatting powershell Get-Content byte code from file

Tags: powershell, hex, hexdump

I am able to get the byte code but 2 things I am trying to do here is

1. format the bytecode so that there are 2 digits per byte. The leading zeroes are excluded.
2. Remove spaces between the bytes themselves because they are taking up a lot of space.

```
gc -Raw -encoding byte "c:\picture.jpg" | % {write-host ('{0:x}' -f $_) -noNewline};
```

tried trim() but not sure if that is possible or where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest - and most efficient - solution is to **use .NET APIs**:

In ***Windows PowerShell***, use [`System.BitConverter.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToString), and remove the resulting `-` separators afterwards:

```bash
[System.BitConverter]::ToString(
  (Get-Content -Raw -Encoding Byte c:\picture.jpg)
) -replace '-'
```

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, use [`System.Convert.ToHexString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToHexString), which directly yields the desired format:

```bash
[System.Convert]::ToHexString(
  (Get-Content -Raw -AsByteStream c:\picture.jpg)
)
```

Note:

- In principle, the Windows PowerShell solution also works in PowerShell (Core), if it weren't for the frivolous syntactic change from `-Encoding Byte` to `-AsByteStream` that occurred between the two PowerShell editions - see [GitHub issue #7986](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7986).

Comment: I'm looking for a command that does this since it is being run as part of a c++ program

Comment: @shawnixer, I don't understand your comment. You're free to invoke the above from any environment, either via the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)) or - from a .NET application - via the [PowerShell SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart).

Comment: You are correct, I was focused on something else. Thank you.